# Show all lines in matplotlib line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I bring the other line to the front or show both the graphs together?

```
plot_yield_df.plot(figsize=(20,20))
```

[image: output]

Comment: You can use `plt.subplots` to specify two different axes to plot to, the `zorder` argument may also be used to determine which plot is "front". I would also consider a moving average for that data to remove some of the noise.

Comment: I'd guess they're both there - one just overlaps with the other. Probably `PREDICTED_YIELD` is scaled incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If plot data overlaps, then one way to view both the data is increase the linewidth along with handling transparency, as shown:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(5), [5, 8, 6, 9, 4], label='Original', linewidth=5, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(np.arange(5), [5, 8, 6, 9, 4], label='Predicted')
plt.legend()
```

[image: plt]

Subplotting is other good way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

The lines are plotted in the order their columns appear in the dataframe. So for example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(400)*0.9
b = np.random.rand(400)+1
a = np.c_[a,-a].flatten()
b = np.c_[b,-b].flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : a, "B" : b})

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here the values of `"B"` hide those from `"A"`.

#### Solution 1: Reverse column order

A solution is to reverse their order

```
df[df.columns[::-1]].plot()
```

[image]

That has also changed the order in the legend and the color coding.

#### Solution 2: Reverse z-order

So if that is not desired, you can instead play with the zorder.

```
ax = df.plot()

lines = ax.get_lines()
for line, j in zip(lines, list(range(len(lines)))[::-1]):
    line.set_zorder(j)
```

[image]